# Datatable Primefaces editor does not send updated value for editing

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

Good afternoon people! I'm trying to do an update through the datatable edit the Primefaces, but does not send the value of inputText upgraded to the bean. The process occurs almost correctly, the value is sent and updated, but the old value already loaded into datatable.

can anyone help me on this :)

Forgive my English. I do not speak or write very well ....

listaProduto.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template= "template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="conteudo" >
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
                <p:dataTable  var="prod" value="#{pBean.listaproduto}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" id="listaproduto1" >

                    <p:ajax event="rowEditInit" listener="#{pBean.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" immediate="true"  />
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{pBean.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" /> 

                    <p:column headerText="Id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{prod.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Nome">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.nome}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{prod.nome}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Preço">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.preco}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{prod.preco}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Fornecedor">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.fornecedor}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  value="#{prod.fornecedor}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Categoria">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.categoria}"/>  </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="cate"  value="#{prod.categoria}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>             

                    <p:column style="width:32px">
                        <p:rowEditor  />
                    </p:column> 
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

ProdutoBean

```
package manager;

import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;
import br.com.estoque.model.Produto;

import br.com.estoque.persistence.ProdutoDao;

@ManagedBean(name = "pBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ProdutoBean {

    private Produto produto;
    private List<Produto> listaproduto;

    public ProdutoBean() {
        produto = new Produto();
    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public List<Produto> getListaproduto() {
        try {
            listaproduto = new ProdutoDao().listar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaproduto;
    }

    public void setListaproduto(List<Produto> listaproduto) {
        this.listaproduto = listaproduto;
    }

    public String cadastrar() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        try {
            new ProdutoDao().cadastrar(produto);
            fc.addMessage("formproduto", new FacesMessage(produto.getNome() + "produto cadastrado com sucesso"));

            produto = new Produto();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fc.addMessage("formproduto", new FacesMessage(produto.getNome() + "Não cadastrado"));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println(produto);
        produto = ((Produto) event.getObject());
        System.out.println(produto);
    }

    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edit Cancelled");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using immediate="true" on your p:ajax?

Comment: just a try ... if I take, does not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staff managed to solve. in fact the problem was in my listaprodutos get ... after entering an if and else, testing whether the product list was null, functioned normally.
The cool thing is, as a friend pointed out, always check the values passed by the network browser.
Hugs

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use other type of event, because *rowEditInit* is executing when you click pencil icon, and after edition when you click save icon is executing event *rowEdit*. Therefore try:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{pBean.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs"/>
```

Also forgive my English :)